# query to count how many users are online is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Why it's not working? This shown none error, just the `rowCounter` that returns `0` rows.

Updating the table with `NOW()` function. And the `$user_id` is = to `$_SESSION['user_id']`, the update query is working fine:

```
$uptUltimaAtividade = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET last_activity = NOW() WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$uptUltimaAtividade->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$uptUltimaAtividade->execute();
```

print out on the screen number of users online:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_activity >= NOW()-600");
$rstq = $query->rowCount();
```

Comment: I think the arithmetic you are using may be slightly (not fully) flawed. What type is the column `last_activity`?

Comment: @TheImpaler VARCHAR (20)

Comment: I will strongly suggest to use `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR`, to use date/time arithmetic.

Comment: @TheImpaler Now it's working, thanks.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have a question, should i prepare the `NOW()`? as i do with `:user_id`

Comment: Nope, it's resolved in the database side, not your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INTERVAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_activity BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND NOW();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works on the left side of `BETWEEN`? Is `last_activity` cast into a datetime first and then compared?

Comment: btw it should `INTERVAL 10 MINUTE` ;)